# ssh tunnel interrupted to unlock key - Looking for a single command

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

I'm trying to create an ssh tunnel to access a remote server(A) that can only be accessed via another server(B). I have a key on my local machine(L) to get to the relay server(B) and another key on the relay server(B) to get to the destination server(A).

[local machine(L) with key to relay server(B)] --> [relay server(B) with key to destination server (A)] --> [destination server (A)]

I have a ~/.ssh/config file that looks like this on my local machine(L):

```
Host relay.server(B)
    Hostname relay.server
    Port 22
    User me
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host destination.server(A)
    Hostname destination.server
    Port 1122
    User me
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And I can cludigly get my tunnel working with the following:

running the command: `ssh -N -L 1122:SERVER_PRIVATE_IP:22 relay.server(B)` on my local machine(L). This prompts me for a password to unlock the first key and then appears to hang it does not return a prompt, using the `-f` option or ending with an `&` prevents me from entering the password. However if I `^C` this command after entering the password and then enter `ssh destination.server(A)` I get a prompt to provide a password to unlock the second key afterwhich I am connected to the destination server(A).

I'm looking for a single command that will let me connect to the destination server(A) from my local machine(L) and will prompt me to provide the passwords needed to unlock each key. Or a suggestion for an alternate way of organising things so that I can connect straight to the destination server(A) from my local machine (L) via the relay server (B).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was going to suggest `-f`; I’m sorry to hear that it didn’t work. (You’re *sure* that you tried `-f` without `&`?) I’m out of ideas; good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is you need

- `ProxyCommand` using `nc` to connect through
- `ForwardAgent` to pass along keys
- ensure your public key is part of `.ssh/authorized_keys` on all servers

> ```
> Host relay
>     Hostname        relay.server.fqdn.or.IP
>     User            me
>     IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/id_rsa
>     ForwardAgent    yes
>
> Host destination
>     Hostname        destination.server.fqdn.or.IP
>     User            me
>     IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/id_rsa
>     ProxyCommand    ssh -q relay "nc %h %p"
>     ForwardAgent    yes
> ```

The longer portion.

The `ProxyCommand` option in ssh config runs a command whenever that enclosing `Host` is used. It's typically used with `nc` available from nmap.org, also known as `ncat` and has lots of options.

In the above `Host destination` entry of ssh config, `ProxyCommand` was set to `ssh -q relay "nc %h %p"` which says, ssh to relay quietly and run `nc destination.server.fqdn.or.IP 22`.

`nc` makes the connection between the incoming ssh and the destination.

The `ForwardAgent yes` tells ssh to add the key to an ssh-agent. ssh agents keep track of the keys and are used to automatically pass the right one to a host as needed. The `ForwardAgent yes` tells the agent to pass the key along to another agent on the relay and then again to the destination.

Now for all this to work, each server you hop through and ultimately the destination must have the public key associated with your private key (id_rsa) in its `.ssh/authorized_keys` file. When you created your private key, id_rsa, a public key, id_rsa.pub, should also have been created.

If you don't have your public key, you can always get it from the private key via `ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa` for easy copy/paste. Note that the public key has 2 or 3 space-separated fields but is **one** line.

So, `ssh relay`, edit `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (which may not exist, so `mkdir -p ~/.ssh` may be necessary) and paste the public key on a new line (or the first if not present).

While on the relay server, check that `nc` exists in /bin or /usr/bin. If it doesn't, then you'll need to install it using your package manager, either yum or apt-get.

From the relay server, `ssh destination` and do the same update of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

`exit` out all the way to your local machine, and you should be able to `ssh destination`

Answer (score 1):

Newer OpenSSH versions allow `ProxyJump` in `.ssh/config`:

```
Host relay
    Hostname        relay.server.fqdn.or.IP
    User            me
    IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    ForwardAgent    yes

Host destination
    Hostname        destination.server.fqdn.or.IP
    ProxyJump       relay
    User            me
    IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```